# Handling Zip Files Without Third Party Lib in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

There is a similar question for 3.5 here:

[Is there a built-in zip library in .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593026/is-there-a-built-in-zip-library-in-net-3-5)

that speculated that 4.0 would have it, but I can't find any info about it.  If not, does anyone know why not?  Seems like it would be fairly high on the list of things to include support for.

Comment: Looking for [`System.IO.Compression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx)?

Comment: no: "... this class does not inherently provide functionality for adding files to or extracting files from .zip archives."

Comment: True, but it still enables you to roll your own. If you search around for "GZipStream multiple files" you'll see a lot of people have done just that.

Comment: The top result I saw for that search is a "roll your own" format that combines multiple files and then gzips them. Doesn't make much sense to me. Why re-invent .tar.gz? There are good tar libraries out there for .NET, they do gzip (using GZipStream), and they are interoperable with a format and a bunch of tools that have been around since 1996. Why invent something different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not for 4.0, but a `ZipArchive` class is being considered for the next version. You can find details about this on the [BCL Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/28/working-with-zip-files-in-net.aspx).

Edit: Otherwise, assuming that it's still available, and depending on your definition of built in (at least it comes/came with Visual Studio), you might be able to use the J# classes to zip files as described in this article: [Using the Zip Classes in the J# Class Libraries to Compress Files and Data with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx)

Edit2: Though note the comments below, that the J# option is probably not the right option except in certain unusual circumstances.

Comment: Ohmygosh no, don't use the J# libraries. They are out of support now, if I am not mistaken, for about 4 years. Also based on Java 1.1.4, and NO security fixes in any of them. Use a real zip library.

Comment: @Cheeso: I wouldn't recommend it in general, I use sharpziplib myself, but I know that there can sometimes be companies that doesn't allow those kind of libraries but might be ok with using the J# libraries since they came with VS, so in certain situations using an older version of VS, it might be an option.

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at the [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace, which contains support for ZIP files, but not all of the features of ZIP files.

Still, it might be enough for your needs.

Comment: Attempting to use these classes, I found they were able to work with things like Nuget-packages and similar "bundles" (probably XAP-files too) but unable to parse regular ZIP-files as such.

If your use-case is limited to parsing these sorts of files, the System.IO.Packaging namespace should be sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

You may have already moved along, but ZiP API is added in .NET 4.5

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx

go nuts.

Comment: OP asked for .NET 4.0

Answer (score -2):

Most easiest to deal with, is with sample code here.

You need to add a new assembly just to find he Zip archive.

[Working with Zip files in .NET 4.5](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/10/19/working-with-zip-files-in-net/)

Comment: OP question was about .NET 4.0