# Zipping files in ASP.NET without using free third-party solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, zip

Do C# support zipping multiple files without using free third-party solutions. I knew there are some third-party solutions such as DotNet zip, SharpZipLib etc... did this, but I would like to create a one without using any of the above.

I see using J# (vjslib.dll) we can use GZip but J# is currently retired and not included in VS2010.

Can you point me to the correct place of this implementation?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid third-party solutions?

Comment: See [Handling Zip Files Without Third Party Lib in .NET 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945209/handling-zip-files-without-third-party-lib-in-net-4-0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is always [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a) which features a class called [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.100%29).
The ability to write real *.zip files  will only be added in .NET 4.5 ([see System.IO.Compression in 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a%28v=vs.110%29)).

So for now you can either try to write your own implementation (not recommended) or use a third-party component. Depending on the license of the component, you might be able to copy its code into your project (making patches to the component a bit cumbersome). The GPL for instance only requires you to release your source code when you distribute your derivative work. But in the case of a web application where no code or binary is actually given away, there are no consequences to using a GPL-ed library.

Answer (score 4):

If at any point your mind changes and you want free third party option i guess this the the best you can get.

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 DotNetZip - makes things real simple. If you want to tinker for some reason, you have source.

Comment: DotNetZip is nice of course. But the question was zipping files **without using free third-party solutions**