# How do I parse information from a zip or compound file in c#?

Tags: c#, parsing, zip

I'm new to c# and programming in general. I've started to create my own powerpoint plugin. I've got it to where a user can browse for a zip file but now I need to know - How do I parse information from a file within that zip or compound file in c#?

Do I have to use a library? If so how do I go about that?

Comment: Top google hit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your issue, [you can accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234). Then you can also upvote one or several answers with the gray up-arrow.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the `System.IO.Compression` namespace has the [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) class for creating/extracting zip files. However, they are only available in .NET 4.5 however, which is currently only available as part of the Visual Studio 2012 RC.

See `System.IO.Compression` in:

- [.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a)
- [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a%28v=vs.110%29)

Up until this point, the de-facto standard for working with zip files in .NET has been the [DotNetZip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It is available under the open-source [MS-PL license](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/license).

Also see:

- [Handling Zip Files Without Third Party Lib in .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945209/handling-zip-files-without-third-party-lib-in-net-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

To work with ZIP-files in general, use the [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class that represents a ZIP file, or the members of the static [`ZipFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) class to work with ZIP files, and use the [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) class to read the contents of a compressed file.

To easily read the contents of a binary file, use the [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) class. Otherwise, use the [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) class for text files.