# How to extract zip file on server via ftp on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wanna unzip a file from "Default.aspx" located on "Site1.Com" to "Site2.Com" that my zip file locates on "Site2.Com", can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx). You'll need .NET 4.5.

Look into [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) to get the root of the server and you can use the relative location from there to get to your files.

Comment: actually i want to unzip a file that is located on other server, i mean i want to unzip "1.zip" on another server using ftp.

Comment: Well you're gonna need to receive the file and unzip it and then send it back. See [Handling Zip Files Without Third Party Lib in .NET 4.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945209/handling-zip-files-without-third-party-lib-in-net-4-0) for Zip support for .NET 4. Or if the files are different virtual directories on the same server you could create a service to do it for you.

Comment: What @Romoku said - there's no way to tell a server "You should unzip that file in place" unless the server has a process in place to do that.  Instead, you'd have to pull it down and send it back.  It might be possible to do that entirely in memory, but you're still sending data both ways and using your local CPU to unzip.

Comment: no no, look i have a page "www.site.com/Modules.aspx" in this page i have module list with button, by clicking on button "newsModule.zip" will copy to "www.RemoteSite.com/Modules" now i want to unzip it from "www.Site.Com" remotely !

Comment: If you have the file already on the server at one point then why don't you just unzip it then or persist it to the file system or cache to be unzipped later?

Comment: What they are saying is that services on www.RemoteSite.com will need to do the unzipping, if the zip file is what is transferred (and in the file system on RemoteSite.com), not Site.com. Otherwise, Site.com will need to send over tehe unzipped contents.