# Unzipping a Stream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I'm working in C#, and I'm downloading for the internet a zip file with one XML file in it. and I wish to load this XML file. This is what I have so far:

```
byte[] data;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
try {
    data = webClient.DownloadData(downloadUrl);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error in DownloadData (Ex:{0})", ex.Message);
    throw;
}

if (data == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("Bulk data is null");
    throw new Exception("Bulk data is null");
}

//Create the stream
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

//Gzip
GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

//Load report straight from the gzip stream
try {
    document.Load(gzipStream);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error in Load (Ex:{0})", ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

in `document.Load` I'm always getting the following exception:
The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you downloading a `GZip` or a `Zip`? The two are not the same.

Comment: `zip != gzip` - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29

Comment: I guess this is my first mistake. It's a zip file not Gzip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using SharpZipLib and it's working great !

Below is a function that encapsulate the library

```
 public static void Compress(FileInfo sourceFile, string destinationFileName,string destinationTempFileName)
        {
            Crc32 crc = new Crc32();
            string zipFile = Path.Combine(sourceFile.Directory.FullName, destinationTempFileName);
            zipFile = Path.ChangeExtension(zipFile, ZIP_EXTENSION);

            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(zipFile))
            {
                using (ZipOutputStream zOut = new ZipOutputStream(fs))
                {
                    zOut.SetLevel(9);
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(ZipEntry.CleanName(destinationFileName));

                    entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    entry.ZipFileIndex = 1;
                    entry.Size = sourceFile.Length;

                    using (FileStream sourceStream = sourceFile.OpenRead())
                    {
                        crc.Reset();
                        long len = sourceFile.Length;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                        while (len > 0)
                        {
                            int readSoFar = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            crc.Update(buffer, 0, readSoFar);
                            len -= readSoFar;
                        }
                        entry.Crc = crc.Value;
                        zOut.PutNextEntry(entry);

                        len = sourceStream.Length;
                        sourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        while (len > 0)
                        {
                            int readSoFar = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            zOut.Write(buffer, 0, readSoFar);
                            len -= readSoFar;
                        }
                    }
                    zOut.Finish();
                    zOut.Close();
                }
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 13):

Apparently SharpZipLib is now unmaintained and you probably want to avoid it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/593030

In .NET 4.5 there is now [built in support for zip files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx), so for your example it would be:

```
var data = new WebClient().DownloadData(downloadUrl);

//Create the stream
var stream = new MemoryStream(data);

var document = new XmlDocument();

//zip
var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(stream);

//Load report straight from the zip stream
document.Load(zipArchive.Entries[0].Open());
```

Comment: If you want support for other compression formats not supported like tgz that supports .NET Core and NETFX try https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress

Answer (score 9):

If you have a byte array that contains a zip archive with a single file, you can use the `ZipArchive` class to get an unzipped byte array with the file's data.
`ZipArchive` is contained in .NET 4.5, in the assembly `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` (you need to reference it explicitly).

The following function, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767078/531158), works for me:

```
public static byte[] UnzipSingleEntry(byte[] zipped)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(zipped))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(entryStream))
                    {
                        return reader.ReadBytes((int)entry.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // To quiet my compiler
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the others have mentioned GZip and Zip are not the same so you might need to use a zip library. I use a library called:  DotNetZip - available from the below site:

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

From [GZipStream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) description:

> Compressed GZipStream objects written to a file with an extension of .gz can be decompressed using many common compression tools; however, this class does not inherently provide functionality for adding files to or extracting files from .zip archives

So unless you control server-side files, I'd suggest looking for specific zip-targeted library (SharpZipLib for example).