# Open ZIP Package from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, zip, memorystream

I want to handle the contents of a ZIP file, that was downloaded, only into memory (without using the hard disk!). `packageStream` contains the bytes of the ZIP file.

```
MemoryStream packageStream = // Stream of downloaded ZIP file    
var zipPackage = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(packageStream, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
var parts = zipPackage.GetParts();
var rels = zipPackage.GetRelationships();
```

`parts` and `rels` do not contain any items.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Is a `MemoryStream` the wrong stream type?

Is the `Package` class the wrong class for ZIP files in **this** scenario?

If you can tell me any alternatives, please no third party projects.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767078/2679485) answer in the duplicated question solved my problem (ZipArchive class). The accepted answer uses a third party project.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767078/3596441

Comment: _"Is a MemoryStream the wrong stream type?"_ Why not just save it to the  file and then try to open it (for test purposes only)?

Comment: @AleksAndreev Tested already successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you can handle .zip files, depends on the Framework version you are using. Streams are fully interchangeable and can even encapsulate one another. The question is if you **have** a class that can actually take a stream and do zip Operations.

If you have at least Framework 4.5, you got the [ZipArchive class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) and this whole thing is childsplay. The examples take a Stream and it can be any implemention of the Stream abstract class. All that memory stream is, is a readyonly stream.

If you are under that, I am pretty sure you are hosed. There simply **is** no class that can take a Stream and do ZIP operations on it before 4.5. Most approaches invovle saving the .zip file on the disk and decompressing it using a console programm with IO redirection. Both Windows ZIP functionaltiy and 7zip work for that, but both involve writing on the Disk.

Perhaps you can use the code part of 7-zip to do a in-process/in memory zip operation. But that might be a tricky.

Comment: ZipArchive class did it... Thanks!