# Create a .zip folder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am currently working on a web project where the user can upload files freely by clicking on a link (a href tag) :

```
textHTML.Append("<a href='download.aspx?file=" + PathFile[i] + "' title='" + Title[i] + " (" + fileType + ", " + fileSize + ")" + "'>" + _Download + " <font color=\"#999999\">(" + Language[i] + ")</font></a>");
```

in the download.aspx page:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Request["file"]);
Response.TransmitFile("../../img/content/csr_dc_documents/" + Request["file"]);
Response.End();
```

I'm trying to find the best solution to offer the user to download as much as files he wants **at the same time**

So my question is the following: is it possible to create a zip folder containing all the files he selects ? and this without saving anything in the server?
Thanks in advance for your advises

Comment: You can check out the `ZipFile` or `ZipArchive` classes to determine what method works best for you.  You will need to create the file locally and once the download is complete you could remove the file.

Comment: @KSdev, for the record, this is only in 4.0 framework and higher. You will need to use a 3rd party library or your own code with .net 3.5 or lower.

Comment: @gunr2171 Very good point.  I actually run in 3.5 for one of my main GUI, so I know the pain.  IF you are not able to use the aforementioned check out this previous [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593026/is-there-a-built-in-zip-library-in-net-3-5) where a library for 3.5 is discussed.

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.0 or later, you can create a [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a `MemoryStream`, and then send the contents of that stream to the user. All without accessing the file system. Implementation is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the .Net 4.5 framework, you can create a zip archive of any and all the files you desire by using the System.IO.Compression ZipFile or ZipArchive classes. See [MSDN System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Compression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for all the details. Several examples are posted throughout the material on how to create zip archives, add entries, and extract entries and the entire archive.